# Two Cells In One UICollectionView Xcode

Tags: ios, swift

[ I want to use two custom cells in one UICollectionView and this is by far I have been trying and I am stuck. Cell one for first and row and cell two of the second row and again cell one for 3rd, you get the point.

here is the code ]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var CV: UICollectionView!
    
    let labelArray = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
    let imageArray = [UIImage(named: "one"), UIImage(named: "two"), UIImage(named: "three"), UIImage(named: "four") ]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        CV.delegate = self
        CV.dataSource = self
        CV.reloadData()
        
//        let nibCellOne = UINib(nibName: "CVCellOne", bundle: nil)
//        let nibCellTwo = UINib(nibName: "CVCellTwo", bundle: nil)
//        CV.register(nibCellOne, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CVCellOne")
//        CV.register(nibCellTwo, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CVCellTwo")
        CV.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CVCellOne")
        CV.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CVCellTwo")
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell1 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CVCellOne", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
                cell1.cellOneLabel.text = labelArray[indexPath.row]
                return cell1

            }
            else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CVCellTwo", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
           
            cell2.cellTwoLabel.text = labelArray[indexPath.row]
            return cell2
        } else if indexPath.section == 2 {
            let cell1 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CVCellOne", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
            cell1.cellOneImage.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
            cell1.cellOneLabel.text = labelArray[indexPath.row]
            return cell1
        } else {
            let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CVCellTwo", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
            cell2.cellTwoImage.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
            cell2.cellTwoLabel.text = labelArray[indexPath.row]
            return cell2
        }
    }


}
```

[This is the customCell xib file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa04K.jpg)

Comment: You should compare indexPath.row

Comment: `indexPath.item` for a collection view

Comment: What is the issue you're facing? Are the cells appearing incorrectly or do they not display at all?

Comment: Alan S. They don't display at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you need is every even row to use Cell1, and every odd row to use Cell2, then don't check for the specific row, check for the remainder when you divide by 2 (modulus)  indexPath.item % 2 == 0

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.item % 2 == 0 {
        let cell1 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CVCellOne", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell1.cellOneLabel.text = labelArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell1
        }
    } else {
        let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CVCellTwo", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell2.cellTwoLabel.text = labelArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell1
        }
    }
}
```